# Python command to create no-arch rpm's

Tags: python, rpm, distutils

I am creating rpm's for my project which is in pure python. I am running the command

> python setup.py bdist_rpm

to build the rpm. This is creating architechture specific rpm's (x86 or x86-64). What I would like is to have a no-arch rpm. Can any of python guru's help me with creating a no-arch rpm. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your software does not contain extension modules (modules written in C/C++), distutils will make the RPM noarch.  I don’t think there’s a way to explicitly control it.